# How do I pass reference to $(function function() ) in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Within my JS file I have a function called `getRippleVals()` that makes a call to a JSON file via a url, this function executes every 5 seconds after the page is loaded, this function is called by `$( document ).ready(function () {})`. I also have a button that has an onclick function attached called `changecoin(coin)`.

What I'd like to do is make it so that when the button is clicked, it calls `getRippleVals()` and passes a string parameter to change the JSON url that it makes the call to. And then, every call to getRippleVals() after the button has been clicked uses the new URL.

At the moment, I have got it worked by using a global variable called `JSONurl` which the function uses to find the JSON file. When the button is clicked the value of `JSONurl` is changed. However at the moment this doesn't immediately call the `getRippleVals()` function, which means that I have to wait a few seconds before the function is called again before the page updates.

I'm not sure how I'm supposed to do this, as I'm not sure how to pass a parameter to a function that is called by `$( document ).ready(function () {})`

Here is my JS:

```
var JSONurl = "http://coincap.io/page/XRP"

document.getElementById("dropdown-btc").addEventListener("click", function(){
    changeCoin("btc");
});

document.getElementById("dropdown-eth").addEventListener("click", function(){
    changeCoin("eth");
});

document.getElementById("dropdown-xrp").addEventListener("click", function(){
    changeCoin("xrp");
});



$( document ).ready(function () {
    console.log( "ready!" );


  $(function getRippleVals() {
      console.log("");
      $.getJSON(JSONurl,
              function (data) {

              //... extra function methods are here, not relevant to the problem.


          });
      setTimeout(getRippleVals, 5000);
      });
});



function changeCoin(coin){
  console.log(coin);
  var coin = coin.toUpperCase();
  $("#dropdownMenuButton").html(coin);

  if(coin === "BTC")
  {
    JSONurl = "http://coincap.io/page/BTC";
    $("#pairing-text").html("BTC : USD");
    lastPrice = 0;
  }
  else if(coin === "ETH")
  {
    JSONurl = "http://coincap.io/page/ETH";
    $("#pairing-text").html("ETH : USD");
    lastPrice = 0;
  }
  else if(coin === "XRP")
  {
    JSONurl = "http://coincap.io/page/XRP";
    $("#pairing-text").html("XRP : USD");
    lastPrice = 0;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

why not do it like this?

```
document.getElementById("dropdown-btc").addEventListener("click", function(){
    changeCoin("btc");
});

document.getElementById("dropdown-eth").addEventListener("click", function(){
    changeCoin("eth");
});

document.getElementById("dropdown-xrp").addEventListener("click", function(){
    changeCoin("xrp");
});



$( document ).ready(function () {
    console.log( "ready!" );
    var JSONurl = "http://coincap.io/page/XRP"
    //call getRippleVals() and pass the JSONurl, it will execute after 5 sec
    setTimeout(getRippleVals(JSONurl), 5000);
});


function getRippleVals(JSONurl){
    $.getJSON(JSONurl,
              function (data) {

              //... extra function methods are here, not relevant to the problem.


          });
      });
}



function changeCoin(coin){
  console.log(coin);
  var coin = coin.toUpperCase();
  $("#dropdownMenuButton").html(coin);

  if(coin === "BTC")
  {
    JSONurl = "http://coincap.io/page/BTC";
    getRippleVals(JSONurl)
    $("#pairing-text").html("BTC : USD");
    lastPrice = 0;
  }
  else if(coin === "ETH")
  {
    JSONurl = "http://coincap.io/page/ETH";
    getRippleVals(JSONurl)
    $("#pairing-text").html("ETH : USD");
    lastPrice = 0;
  }
  else if(coin === "XRP")
  {
    JSONurl = "http://coincap.io/page/XRP";
    getRippleVals(JSONurl)
    $("#pairing-text").html("XRP : USD");
    lastPrice = 0;
  }

}
```

The reason you have to wait 5 sec to execute the `getRippleVals()` because you call the `setTimeout` inside the `getRippleVals()`

**Edit**

Sorry for later reply. As for your request I already made a sample code below.

```
var JSONurl = "http://coincap.io/page/XRP";
var counter = 5000;
var timer = null;
$(document).ready(function(){
      getRippleValstimer(); //call the timer so getRippleVals() will execute every 5sec
        //will execute 5 sec after page load
        document.getElementById("dropdown-btc").addEventListener("click", function(){
          changeCoin("btc");
      });

      document.getElementById("dropdown-eth").addEventListener("click", function(){
          changeCoin("eth");
      });

      document.getElementById("dropdown-xrp").addEventListener("click", function(){
          changeCoin("xrp");
      });
});

//the timer function
function getRippleValstimer(){
      timer = setTimeout(function(){
        getRippleValstimer(); getRippleVals();
      },counter);
}

function getRippleVals(){
  //your code here
  console.log(JSONurl);
}


function changeCoin(coin){
  var coin = coin.toUpperCase();
  console.log(coin);
  if(coin === "BTC")
  {
    JSONurl = "http://coincap.io/page/BTC";
    clearTimeout(timer); //clear the timer
    getRippleVals();//call getRippleVals() so it will execute without waiting for 5 seconds
    getRippleValstimer(); //initialize the timer function again

  }
  else if(coin === "ETH")
  {
    JSONurl = "http://coincap.io/page/ETH";
    clearTimeout(timer); //clear the timer
    getRippleVals();//call getRippleVals() so it will execute without waiting for 5 seconds
    getRippleValstimer(); //initialize the timer function again
  }
  else if(coin === "XRP")
  {
    JSONurl = "http://coincap.io/page/XRP";
    clearTimeout(timer); //clear the timer
    getRippleVals();//call getRippleVals() so it will execute without waiting for 5 seconds
    getRippleValstimer(); //initialize the timer function again
  }

}
```

Comment: I've now changed my code to this: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9f642d1fcb443cefca23192bb969b242 I want the function to be called once upon page load, and then every 5 seconds after that. This code is calling the function on page load but it isn't being refreshed every 5 secs, why isn't this happening?

Comment: sorry for later reply. I just updated my answer. Please check it out.